# Passing Post ID to separate controller from Posts/index.html.erb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller

I am trying to allow for voting on posts in a Ruby on Rails blog that I created. I don't really want to go the plugin or gem route because I think I am close. Here is the situation:

I am displaying all my posts in /posts/index.html.erb through the partial _post.html.erb. With each post I am rendering the following code for the vote button:

```
   <% remote_form_for [@post, Vote.new] do |f| %>
     <%= f.hidden_field :ip_address, :value => "#{request.remote_ip}" %>
     <%= submit_tag 'Me Too', :class => 'voteup' %>
   <% end %>
```

Which sends the request through the votes controller:

```
  def create
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @vote = @post.votes.create!(params[:vote])


       respond_to do |format|
       format.html { redirect_to @posts}
       format.js
     end
  end
```

The error I am getting is `Couldn't find Post without an ID` which makes sense because I am not on the /posts/show.html.erb page.

Is there a way that I can pass the post_id to the votes_controller (and into the post_id column in the votes table) from the /posts/index.html.erb view?

Comment: in `VotesController#create` add some junk text like `asdas` (just to cause an error when that method gets called). Then vote. The error will display the params being recevied. What's those params showing?

Comment: Where exactly do I put the junk text within the method? Just before the first line (the @post line)?

Comment: yes, just after `def create`, in next line add `asdfasfsf`. It's just a easy way to see what params the controller action was called with. Of course, there is one plugin for this (can't recall the name), but this method works well :)

Comment: This is what I get: NameError (undefined local variable or method `asdfasdfasdfasdf' for #<VotesController:0x102d81230>)

Comment: Yes, that's what was intended. But below in that error you get, is a section called `Request` , `Parameters:`. What are the parameters?

Comment: {"vote"=>{"ip_address"=>"127.0.0.1"},
 "commit"=>"Vote Up ↑",
 "authenticity_token"=>"XhrF3JCeO5GaiiGq8CTgpLjZasWLbN8FZob0owuHapQ="}

Comment: yes, see my answer. It should work. Don't forget to remove the junk text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this in the view, after the `remote_form_for` :

```
<%= f.hidden_field :post_id, :value => @post.id %>
```

You might also need to to this in the `def create`

```
@post = Post.find(params[:vote][:post_id]) #note the added [:vote]
```

If you look at the params after those changes, it should show:

```
{"vote"=>{"ip_address"=>"127.0.0.1", "post_id"=> >>actual-post-id-here<< },
"commit"=>"Vote Up ↑" ..........
```

Also, I recommend having a look at the **excellent *[RailsCasts by Ryan Bates](http://railscasts.com/episodes/archive)***. Lots of great video tutorials there.

Comment: I get this error: Called id for nil, which would mistakenly be 4 -- if you really wanted the id of nil, use object_id

Comment: What's the first line in the error section `Application Trace` (click on `Aplication Trace`)

Comment: Also, join the chat room at SO : http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24/ruby-rails. I want to avoid cluttering up your question! And hurry, I have 30 minutes

Comment: /Users/bgadoci/brandon_gadoci/app/views/posts/_post.html.erb:12:in `_run_erb_app47views47posts47_post46html46erb_locals_post_post_counter_object'